# How to find out a div's name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I read the name of a div with javascript or Jquery?

I have code that dynamically creates divs with the same name and appends an ascending number to make the div unique. ex:

How can I "read" the div Id?

```
$(this).divname()
```

or something....

Comment: Are you want div id or name

Comment: I'm assuming you meant a given id; in that case, it's simply `this.id`.

Answer (score 3):

If `this` refers to the div element then `this.id` will give the id value, `$(this).attr('name')` should give the name attribute value

- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

For ID

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

For Name

```
$(this).attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Get the id for that particular div. Use attr and prop in jquery.

```
 getId = $(this).attr('id');
 getName = $(this).attr('name');
```

> Note : jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values
>   into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause
>   inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a
>   way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves
>   attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways depend on the requirments

```
var variableName = $(this).attr('name');
var variableName = $(this).attr('id');
var variableName = $("#id").attr('find any attribute'); // name, id, class and so on
var variableName = $("div#id").attr('find any attribute'); // name, id, class and so on
var variableName = $(".class").attr('find any attribute'); // name, id, class and so on
var variableName = $("div.class").attr('find any attribute'); // name, id, class and so on
var variableName = $("div[id='test']").attr('find any attribute'); // name, id, class and so on
var variableName = $("div[class='testing']").attr('find any attribute'); // name, id, class and so on
var variableName = $("div[name='header']").attr('find any attribute'); // name, id, class and so on
```

use any of them which fit on your requirement... and `this` keyword refer to current object.

For example if I create a click function and directly I call div **CLASS** like

```
$(".test").click(function(){ this.id /*OR*/ (this).id /*OR*/ $(this).attr("name") });
```

**OR** indirectly call div **CLASS** like

```
$("div[class='test']").click(function(){ this.id /*OR*/ (this).id /*OR*/ $(this).attr("name") });
```

Now `click` function will give me the current object(s) ids **BUT** in selector if I use `this` keyword

```
$(this).click(function(){ this.id /*OR*/ (this).id /*OR*/ $(this).attr("any attribute name") });
```

now where ever I click at document any where it'll give me the **ID** and some where give me undefined **OR** also error so it depends on selector.

For example now you've multiple div, span **OR** any object with same class but different ids when you click at any div **OR** span it'll give current id because of `this.id` so `this` refer to current object.

**So most of the time we use direct seletor to get any attribute like this**

```
$("#test").attr("name");
```

Comment: Hmm...interesting use of `var` here...really!

Comment: my mistake I missed the variable name!!!

Answer (score 0):

If `$(this)` refers to the div you are talking about, then

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

returns either div id or undefined,

```
$(this).attr('name')
```

returns either div name or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function that will return the div name if you pass an id to it:

```
function returnName(id){
    var name = $('#'+id).attr('name');
    return name;
}
```

To use this function:

```
var currentDivId = $(this).attr('id');
var myDivName = returnName(currentDivId);
```